# SonarQube doesn't comment on GitHub pull requests

Tags: github, sonarqube, travis-ci, pull-request

I'm trying to set up `SonarQube` to comment on my GitHub pull requests after a successful Travis build.

I've already have normal analysis working. For the pull request analysis I also have all tokens in place, plugins installed, etc. Issues in the pull request are successfully identified: the debug log shows successful HTTP requests where the server responds with the relevant issues. Some lines of the log:

```
15:06:10.194 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
15:06:10.197 DEBUG: Post-jobs : GitHub Pull Request Issue Publisher (wrapped)
15:06:10.197 INFO: Executing post-job GitHub Pull Request Issue Publisher (wrapped)
```

On GitHub I can see that the oauth token used by sonar is actually being used.

When adding commits to a pull request, there even is a status for sonarqube: when a new commit is added, for a short while it is waiting for a response, then it changes to `"SonarQube reported no issues"`. Note that this status appears before the sonar scanner has ran on Travis.

Does anyone know what could be the problem or what I could do to debug this any further? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And are you sure there are any violations to report on in the changed lines of the pull request? If there's nothing to report for the changeset, there won't be any comments.

Comment: @janos Yes, I am sure. The exact changes that should be reported are the ones that I can retrieve by doing a HTTP request to the URL that shows up in the log, as described in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I emphasized this enough. I'm talking about violations in the *changeset*, not the project, and not even the files involved in the changeset, but specifically the lines in the *diff* of the pull request. The plugin filters the issues of the project to only comment on what is new in the diff alone. So, you're certain that the commits in the pull request have some violations?

Comment: I am absolutely sure. I created some issues for this purpose.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have exactly the same problem!

Comment: Sadly, I wasn't. I'm no longer actively trying to solve this problem, but a solution would be highly appreciated. Maybe I'll pick it up in the future. If you find anything, let me know!

Comment: Make sure you pass the correct sonar.github.pullRequest, in my case I have to do some workaround to replace this properties on sonar-project.properties file from github pull request plugin variable $ghprbPullId

Comment: same issue here :(

Answer (score 5):

in case it helps, I was having the same issue. This [issue report](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/issues/3) helped me.

To summarize, this problem can be due to one or more of the following factors:

1. Sonarqube's analysis mode needs to be set to preview (-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview) otherwise it seems it won't attempt to connect to GitHub; it will store the results in the SonarQube database.
2. If the issues found in your code as a result of the scan have already been saved to the SonarQube's database, it won't send them to GitHub, in other words, there need to be new issues when you run it in preview mode for them to be sent to GitHub.
3. An obvious one, but always good to double check, make sure your oauth credentails are correct and the parameters named correctly.
4. Double check the properties "Plugins accepted for Preview mode" and "Plugins excluded for Preview mode" in SonarQube Admin settings (General section) to ensure the Github plugin hasn't been excluded.

There might be more, but hopefully this will help. The ones that were getting me were number 1 and 2.

Comment: Hi sorry to ask a question in someone else's question. but when i enable github in preview mode, my build fails for no language plugins are installed. I'm using modules (not sure if that matters)

Comment: I'm not sure @PeterLai, try asking as a separate question and maybe someone will be able to help you

Comment: preview is no longer supported.

Answer (score -1):

Pull Requests are now a first-class citizen feature in SonarQube for Developer, Enterprise and Data Center Edition users.

As [described here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrade-notes/), Sonarqube 7.2 + Community Edition won't support pull request analysis